# Why my table isn't showing correctly?

Tags: tables

I have a long table that should look like this , the table has several rows and cannot be in just one page  :

[image]

I created the following table code :

```
     % \usepackage{multirow}


\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|l|l|cl|} 
\hline
Test function                                                                                                                                                            & Study domain                      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{initial obtained solution (Algorithm 2 )}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Obtained hybrid optimizer solution\\ ( Algorithm\textasciitilde{} 3 ) \end{tabular}}                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Objective function value \\ of the solution \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textasciitilde{} Sphere \\\textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{} ( dim = 14 ) \textasciitilde{} \end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{$ [-5,5]^{14} $ } & $N_ter=6 N=22 P=5 ~ $                                                                                                                  & \multirow{2}{*}{$X1=1 X2=-0.1 X3=1.0 X4=-1 X5=-1 X6=0.90 X7=0.8 X8=-0.9 X9=0.16 X10=0.14 X11=-0.2 X12=0.6 X13=0.33 ~ $ } & \multirow{2}{*}{$X1=-0.03 X2=-0.05 X3=-0.04 X4=-0.03 X5=0.005 X6=-0.07 X7=0.04 X8=-0.05 X9=0.05 X10=0.05 X11=-0.04 X12=-0.05 X13=0.05  ~ $ } & \multirow{2}{*}{$~0.03~ $ }                                                                           &                        \\ 
\cline{3-3}
                                                                                                                                                                         &                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\\ $~Iter =10 $\\$\alpha=0.1$\\$\gama=0.3$\textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{} \end{tabular} &                                                                                                                                                                                            &                                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                                                                           &                        \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Unfortunetly , the table isn't showing correctly after compiling :

[image]

**MWE of the problem :**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|l|l|cl|} 
\hline
Test function                                                                                                                                                            & Study domain                      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{initial obtained solution (Algorithm 2 )}                                                                                                                                                                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Obtained hybrid optimizer solution\\ ( Algorithm\textasciitilde{} 3 ) \end{tabular}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Objective function value \\ of the solution \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textasciitilde{} Sphere \\\textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{} ( dim = 14 ) \textasciitilde{} \end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{$ [-5,5]^{14} $ } & $N_ter=6 N=22 P=5 ~ $                                                                                                                  & \multirow{2}{*}{$X1=1 X2=-0.1 X3=1.0 X4=-1 X5=-1 X6=0.90 X7=0.8 X8=-0.9 X9=0.16 X10=0.14 X11=-0.2 X12=0.6 X13=0.33 ~ $ } & \multirow{2}{*}{$X1=-0.03 X2=-0.05 X3=-0.04 X4=-0.03 X5=0.005 X6=-0.07 X7=0.04 X8=-0.05 X9=0.05 X10=0.05 X11=-0.04 X12=-0.05 X13=0.05 ~ $ } & \multirow{2}{*}{$~0.03~ $ }                                                                               &                        \\ 
\cline{3-3}
                                                                                                                                                                         &                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\\ $~Iter =10 $\\$\alpha=0.1$\\$\gama=0.3$\textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{}\textasciitilde{} \end{tabular} &                                                                                                                          &                                                                                                                                             &                                                                                                           &                        \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I wish the problem is clear for you !
Thank you a lot for help !

Comment: It seems that your table is to wide to fit in page. Please, extend your code fragment to MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete, compilable document, which we can test and then propose a solution for your problem.

Comment: @Zarko , i added the MWE example !

Comment: Is there any suggestions ?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but what is the purpose of `\textasciitilde{}` and `~` here? I don't see them in the output you show. Apart from that, please make your code compilable. I currently get a bunch of error messages if I try to compile your code. (Hint: you can't use `\\ ` in math mode like you did in some of the columns.)

Comment: How is `\gama` defined?

Comment: $\gamma$ , i think it's a mistake but not related to the problem

Comment: @leandriis . I corrected the issue. You could help by taking the row where "sphere" appairs and by formatting that row. isn't necessary to correct the whole code but it suffies to give a solution with considering just one row as example.

Comment: Your table have (many) errors, do for repairing them we need more times. Be patient ot check your MWE yourself and correct errors in it

Comment: @Zarko , i tryed to repair the code many times but i don't know why the text is floating and the last column isn't showing. In fact , i used this website to create the table : https://www.latex-tables.com/# . Plz visit that website and import the latex code ( there is a button {}import from latex at the top of the website ).

Comment: well, meanwhile a good soul show one possibility you how you can write your table. Your code, as you shown,  has more than 50 errors and lot of clutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following could serve as a place to start from. Depending on the exact requirements further modefication/improvement might still be needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|l|l|l|cl|} 
\hline
Test function 
  & Study domain 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                          initial obtained solution (Algorithm 2 )
                          \end{tabular}} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                            Obtained hybrid\\ 
                            optimizer solution\\ 
                            (Algorithm 3 ) 
                            \end{tabular}} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                             Objective\\ 
                             function\\ 
                             value  of the\\  
                             solution 
                             \end{tabular}} 
          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* 
\hline
\multirow{13}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}   Sphere \\    ( dim = 13 )   \end{tabular}} 
  & \multirow{13}{*}{$ [-6,6]^{13} $ } 
    & $N_ter=5 N=20 P=4   $  
      & \multirow{13}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 
                        $X1=1$ \\ 
                        $X2=-0.15$\\ 
                        $X3=1.07$ \\ 
                        $X4=-1.08$ \\ 
                        $X5=-1.1$ \\ 
                        $X6=0.6$ \\ 
                        $X7=0.5$ \\ 
                        $X8=-0.17$ \\ 
                        $X9=0.12$ \\ 
                        $X10=0.12$ \\ 
                        $X11=-0.28$ \\ 
                        $X12=0.55$ \\ 
                        $X13=0.39  $ \end{tabular} } 
        & \multirow{13}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 
                          $X1=-0.035$ \\ 
                          $X2=-0.09$ \\ 
                          $X3=-0.0$ \\ 
                          $X4=-0.01$ \\ 
                          $X5=0.05$ \\ 
                          $X6=-0.09$ \\ 
                          $X7=0.05$ \\ 
                          $X8=-0.02$ \\ 
                          $X9=0.3$ \\ 
                          $X10=0.04$ \\ 
                          $X11=-0.07$ \\ 
                          $X12=-0.8$ \\ 
                          $X13=0.4   $ \end{tabular}} 
          & \multirow{13}{*}{$ 0.33  $ } &  \\* 
\cline{3-3}
 &  
   & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} 
     $ \text{Iter} =52 $\\
     $\alpha=0.1$\\
     $\gamma=0.9$    
     \end{tabular} 
     &  &  &  &  \\ 
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\ 
     &&&&&& \\ 
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
\hline

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your precious help !

Answer (score 1):

The possibilities with using `aligned` math environment and `longtable` width equal to `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,
            makecell,   
            multirow}   
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering}p{\dimexpr0.11\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                   >{\centering}p{\dimexpr0.09\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                   p{\dimexpr0.23\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                   p{\dimexpr0.19\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                   p{\dimexpr0.19\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                   >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.19\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                  }
    \hline
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering Test function}
    &   \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Study domain}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{initial obtained solution (Algorithm 2)}}
            &   \centering  Obtained hybrid optimizer solution (Algorithm 3)
                &   \multirow{3}{=}{Objective function value  of the solution}          \\
   \hline
\endfirsthead
    \hline
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering Test function}
    &   \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Study domain}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{initial obtained solution (Algorithm 2)}}
            &   \centering  Obtained hybrid optimizer solution (Algorithm 3)
                &   \multirow{3}{=}{Objective function value  of the solution}          \\
   \hline
\endhead
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize    Continue on the next page}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\multirow{15}{=}{Sphere \\ (dim = 13)}
    &  \multirow{15}{=}{$[-6,6]^{13}$}
        &   $N_{\mathrm{te}r}=5,\; N=20,\; P=4$
           &   &   &       \\
    \cline{3-3}
    &   &   $\begin{aligned}
            \text{Iter} & = 50  \\
            \alpha      & = 0.1 \\
            \gamma      & = 0.9 \\[9\baselineskip]
            \end{aligned}$
            &   \multirow[t]{-1.5}{=}{$\begin{aligned}
                X1 & = 1.0077534   \\
                X2 & = -0.1104975   \\
                X3 & =  1.0014137   \\
                X4 & = -1.0036138   \\
                X5 & = -1.9578661   \\
                X6 & =  0.9005066   \\
                X7 & =  0.7631584   \\
                X8 & = -0.1421437   \\
                X9 & =  0.1663432   \\
               X10 & =  0.1404722   \\
               X11 & = -0.233138    \\
               X12 & = 0.5286155    \\
               X13 & = 0.3286869
                \end{aligned}$}
                &   \multirow[t]{-1.5}{=}{$\begin{aligned}
                    X1 & = -0.03192925  \\
                    X2 & = -0.05026519  \\
                    X3 & = -0.04528505  \\
                    X4 & = -0.0326411   \\
                    X5 & =  0.00547415  \\
                    X6 & = -0.0716279   \\
                    X7 & =  0.04580095  \\
                    X8 & = -0.050372    \\
                    X9 & =  0.0503053   \\
                   X10 & =  0.05034414  \\
                   X11 & = -0.0472667   \\
                   X12 & = -0.0584998   \\
                   X13 & =  0.0519024
                    \end{aligned}$}
                    &   \multirow{-4}{*}{$0.029873$}    \\*
     \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]